# Highstock step graph with min-max value

Tags: highcharts

I have a series of json data in a highstock chart and I want to trim this data in values that are only 0 or 1: 0 if the data is 0, else 1. What I have to write in my option? My code now is this:

```
window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'chart_div'
    },

    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },

    title: {
      text: 'prova'
    },

    {% if net.ntype == "ztc" and sens.type == 2 %}

     // HERE I WANT TO DO AN OPTION TO TRIM VALUES
     // TO 0 OR 1

    {% end %}

    series: [{
        name: 'prova',
        data: data,
        step: true,
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
        }
      }]
  })
}
```

Comment: It's not a highstocks problem, why don't you do it on the backend and then pass it as json to your chart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First loop in your Jason using $each() 
Creat an array for example x 
Then add if condition and push to x your date time and value either 0 or 1 
Then your data :x; 
This is just an idea if you can give us your code we can help you more